# Read in PHP an external XML file with a wrong encoding

Tags: php, xml, encoding, rss

I tried to do a `file_get_contents()` from this xml : http://www.leprogres.fr/football/ol/rss, but it looks to me that this xml file is sending wrong information.

Indeed, when I look at the header response and the xml `encoding` attribute, both say `UTF-8` (I think it should be something like `ISO-8859-1`) but my `file_get_contents()` doesn't return the feed as it should, for instance:

> Actualité de l'Olympique Lyonnais – live, vidéo, résultat avec leprogres.fr | Le Progrès`

Becomes :

> ActualitÃ© de l'Olympique Lyonnais â€“ live, vidÃ©o, rÃ©sultat avec leprogres.fr | Le ProgrÃ¨s`

The closer I got to the expected result is by using [forceutf8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8) but it does not convert all the characters, the dash here for instance and the apostrophe a bit later in the xml document are converted to a question mark.

Comment: *forceutf8* is not a good choice because you have already given up when you use that library. it is looking at the wrong place for a "solution". And the XML file is actually UTF-8 encoded, so `file_get_contents` is not a problem here.

Comment: Also I have the feeling that actual code is missing in your question, so a retro-active -1 because there is not much use in this question (and it's answer) for future users in it's current form :/

Comment: @hakre it was of use to me at least.

Comment: Yes, no doubt, but I was talking about future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents` works for me with right encoding but you can use like following as alternative:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.leprogres.fr/football/ol/rss");

echo $xml->channel->title;
```

#### Output

```
Actualité de l'Olympique Lyonnais – live, vidéo, résultat avec leprogres.fr | Le Progrès
```

Comment: Thanks, your alternative works like a charm! I don't understand why the `file_get_contents()` did not work for me though?

Comment: Like i said, it works for me. But i dont know why doesnt work for you. I use always `simplexml` for `XML parsing`. Its so quick